# How can I find the ancestor directory with a given name?

Tags: directory

How can I find the path of a parent directory with a particular name?  For instance, say I have directory `/a/b/c/d/e/f/g` and I want to find the parent directory with name `c`, I would want this to return `/a/b/c`.

The use case is that I'm within a fairly nested directory structure, and I don't want to have to have the difficult to read string of `../../..`, which I would also need to make sure to change when I updated the nesting level of the directory structure in the future.

Not a dealbreaker, but if there were two ancestor directories with the given name, I would ideally want the one with the longest path.  i.e. `/a/b/c/d/e/c/f/g` should ideally return `/a/b/c/d/e/c` instead of `/a/b/c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use parameter substitution, twice.

We start by storing the pathname of the directory in a variable (if you're dealing with the current working directory, you can skip this and use `PWD` in place of `p` later):

```
$ p=/a/b/c/d/e/c/f/g
```

We may then remove the longest prefix string that matches `*/c/` from this:

```
$ echo "${p##*/c/}"
f/g
```

We then realize that if this result was deleted from the *end* of `$p`, we would get the result we want:

```
$ echo "${p%${p##*/c/}}"
/a/b/c/d/e/c/
```

or, to remove that final `/` as well:

```
$ echo "${p%/${p##*/c/}}"
/a/b/c/d/e/c
```

The [standard parameter substitutions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) `${variable##pattern}` and `${variable%pattern}` removes the longest matching prefix string and the shortest matching suffix string respectively.

(To get `/a/b/c`, which you did not want, you would use `#` in place of `##` in the "inner" substitution)